# Add rotate to this hover effect with out a plugin?

Tags: jquery, hover

So this code with move ".now" up 20px when I hover over "#header" and then take it back down when I hover off.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header')
        .hover(function() {
            $(".now").stop().animate({ top: -20 }, 'fast');
        }, function() {
            $(".now").stop().animate({ top: 0 }, 'fast');
        });
});
```

How can I rotate ".now" by say 45deg as well as moving it?

Comment: jQuery Transit is good for this kind of stuff - http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Comment: I was really hoping for this I would not need a plugin of any kind, I thought jquery had a rotate function built in.

Answer (score 0):

Rotating an element is built on CSS3 styling that's handled differently among various *modern* browsers...

Therefore, while there are ways to do it without plugins, using good jQuery plugin like [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) helps simplify the code you need to achieve the effect you desire (much like jQuery itself.)